# How to convert IndexedSeq[Byte] to a utf-8 String efficiently in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm having trouble converting an indexed sequence of bytes to a String, encoded in utf-8.

```
scala> val x : IndexedSeq[Byte] = IndexedSeq(64.toByte, 64.toByte, 64.toByte)
scala> x.mkString
res2: String = 748464
```

Now I can make it work, by converting to an array, and then constructing a new String like so;

```
scala> new String(x.toArray)
res3: String = JT@
```

But allocating and copying twice seems like an overkill.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

You'd want to use the constructor that specifies a Charset.

But you can't avoid copying into the String's underlying value, even from a StringBuilder.

Another idea might be deserialization, but you still get buffering and extra processing to massage the bytes.

For fun:

```
scala> val x : IndexedSeq[Byte] = IndexedSeq(65.toByte, 65.toByte, 65.toByte)
x: IndexedSeq[Byte] = Vector(65, 65, 65)

scala> import collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
import collection.generic.CanBuildFrom

scala> val cbf = new CanBuildFrom[IndexedSeq[Byte], Char, String] {
     | def apply(from: IndexedSeq[Byte]) = apply()
     | def apply() = StringBuilder.newBuilder
     | }
cbf: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[IndexedSeq[Byte],Char,String]{def apply(from: IndexedSeq[Byte]): StringBuilder; def apply(): StringBuilder} = $anon$1@4f820f42

scala> x.map(_.toChar)(cbf)
res0: String = AAA
```